# Selenium with Python on ssh server: InvalidElementStateException & ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, selenium, ssh, quora

I'm trying to log in into **Quora** website.
 On my local machine it runs perfectly.

But on SSH server (droplet on DigitalOcean) - no, I'm getting `InvalidElementStateException`

I've tried to focus on the element by `send_keys(Keys.NULL)`, and got  `ElementNotVisibleException`

Here is the code:

```
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
print("Logging...")

# gets email and password from json
with open('config.json') as f:
    login_data = json.load(f)
email = login_data['email']
password = login_data['pass']
time.sleep(3)
email_field_xpath = "//div[@class='form_column']/input[@name='email']"
password_field_xpath = "//div[@class='form_column']/input[@name='password']"

# webdriver's going to wait max 10 seconds for email's field, password field, login button to display
email_field_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_field_xpath))
password_field_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_field_xpath))

email_field_element.send_keys(Keys.NULL)
email_field_element.clear()
email_field_element.send_keys(email)
password_field_element.send_keys(Keys.NULL)
password_field_element.clear()
password_field_element.send_keys(password)
login_button_xpath = "//input[@value='Login']"
# wait till element is clickable
login_button_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, login_button_xpath)))
login_button_element.click()
print("Logged In.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that screen resolution you are using at your local machine and on SSH server are different. May be the size of opened browser windows are different at both at local and on SSH server.

Try to change your local settings as SSH server's than you can figure out what is actual reason or just try the possible solutions given below.

Possible solutions by focusing on element first. Here, your `element` can be `email_field_element` or `password_field_element`:

1) First move to that element using `ActionChains`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.perform()
```

**OR**

2) You can also use scroll up to that element. Like:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

**OR**

3)Input data using java script.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')" # you can use xpath as well
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: unfortunately, nothing of these helped, but thank you anyway :)

Comment: without `send_keys(Keys.NULL)` on:
`File "quora.py", line 49, in log_in
    email_field_element.clear()`